# Valgrind complains while using realloc functions?

Tags: c, string, valgrind

I have implemented my own version of strcat function.
It works fine but valgrind complains.

```
main()
{
    char *src=NULL;
    src=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
    strcpy(src,"sandeep");
    xstrcat(src,"pathak");
    printf("******FINAL STR IS : %s ********",src);
    free(src);
    src=NULL; 
}

void  xstrcat(char *src,const char *dest)
{
        int dlen=strlen(dest);
        int slen=strlen(src);
        int j=0;
        int i=0;
        char *temp=(char *) realloc(src,(slen+dlen+1)*sizeof(char));
        for(j=slen;i<dlen;i++,j++)
        {
                temp[j]=dest[i];
        }
        temp[j]='\0';
        printf("%s",temp);
}
```

VALGRIND ERROR :

```
==31775== Invalid read of size 4
==31775== Invalid read of size 4
==31775== Invalid read of size 1
==31775== Invalid read of size 1
==31775== 14 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==31775==    at 0x1B9053EE: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:197)
==31775==    by 0x8048606: xstrcat (in /user/gur27268/Computer_Systems/Socket/DevTest/UTI
==31775==    by 0x804850F: main (in /user/gur27268/Computer_Systems/Socket/DevTest/UTIL/a
==31775==
==31775== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31775==    definitely lost: 14 bytes in 1 blocks.
==31775==    possibly lost:   0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==31775==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==31775==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==31775== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.**
==31775== To see them, rerun with: --show-reachable=yes
```

I have freed src, but using realloc tends to this problem...

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Do not [misuse variable names](http://pastehtml.com/view/1dma39d.html)! `src` is **source**: where things come from; `dest` is **destination**: where things go to

Comment: @pmg: But it creates such entertaining bugs...

Comment: please don't cast the return value of malloc( ); sizeof(char) is always 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void xstrcat(char *src,const char *dest) {
```

You're passing src by value, and xstrcat is working on and modifying its local copy. Any changes you make to `src` will not be reflected in the calling function.

```
void xstrcat(char **src,const char *dest) {
  // Work with *src
}

...
xstrcat(&src, ...)
```

This approach lets xstrcat modify main's `src` variable.

To quote a frequently mentioned sample:

```
void foo (int x) {
  x = 2;
}
void bar (int * x) {
  *x = 2;
}
int main() {
  foo(9); // foo cannot modify the literal 9
  int i = 1;
  foo(i); // foo cannot modify the variable i
  bar(&9); // This isn't legal - it can't be
  bar(&i); // bar modifies i
}
```

Comment: I am changing a block(contents) which is pointed to by str ,not the reference ,so no point of having the above issue....the above code works fine ,plz help me figure out that Valgrind issue....thanks

Comment: @Sandeep: Erik is right. When you realloc `src`, it's pure luck that the underlying block containing the allocation you already have happens to be big enough for the new size, so the new address `temp` is the same as `src` and `src` still points to the data you want. This isn't the normal behavior of `realloc`. Try reallocating up to a much larger size, then your code will fail.

Comment: `newvar=realloc(oldvar, ...)` is equivalent to `char * newvar=malloc(...); memcpy(newvar, oldvar); free(oldvar);` - You're freeing the original `src` and main never gets to know that